# Add empty mapping in MultiValuedMap

Tags: java, collections, apache-commons

I am using MultiValuedMap from commons-collections. I am trying to add an entry in the map with an empty list.

Like if you would have a `Map<String, List<String>>` you would `put("string", new ArrayList<String>())`

Can I do this with MultiValuedMap ?

I tried:

```
map.asMap().put(stringValue, new ArrayList<>())
```

and also:

```
map.put(stringValue, null)
```

The first line throws an exception(UnsupportedOperation) and the second one has a `null` value in the list, which I don't want.

Comment: Why do you need this? Since the MultiValuedMap creates the value lists implicitly, it would usually be considered implementation detail whether the list exists or not.

Comment: Much of the functionality of Apache Commons has been superseded by Java 8. You can just use the plain Java API method [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) instead of using MultiValuedMap. Saves you an external dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get` methods returns an empty list if no value is present, so there should be no need to initialize any internal list. It would probably mess with the semantics of methods like `contains(key)` if you had to differentiate between keys that are not present and keys that are mapped to empty collections.

Any behavior like this would be implementation specific and can be different depending on the library version. But even looking at the [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiValueMap.java), it seems you can't have an empty internal list anyway. The internal list is only initialized if it actually contains at least one element and is removed when all elements are removed.